# Spring boot 2 and Angular 6 login problem

Tags: java, angular, spring

I am setting a server with spring boot 2 and angular 6, so far I've done several things with some tutorials and some things by myself but that's not the question.The question and my actual problem is that I am trying to create login so but for some reason I am not able to get it working after I remove .httpBasic and replace it with .formLogin.loginPage I got principal call with null.After I enable httpBasic again I submit my user/pass it works fine but I cannot get it to work without it.As well my angular client is buggy as hell and I don't actually know from where the problem is.

LoginRest.java

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class LoginRest {
    @GetMapping(value = "/login",produces = "application/json")
    public Principal login(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("/login called " + principal);
        return principal;
    }
```

UserPrincipal.java

```java
@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        this.user.getRoles().forEach(r -> {
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + r.getRoleName());
            authorities.add(authority);
        });

        return authorities;
    }
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userPrincipalDetailsService);

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
```

UserPrincipalDetailsService.java

```java
 @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = this.userService.getByEmail(email);
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(user);

        return userPrincipal;
    }
```

and this is my angular 6 project https://bitbucket.org/rumenyavorov/springboot-client/

I just want to get my login working and proceed further with my project and to understand what the hell I was doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no code related to http request in your repo? did u tried anything so far about consuming authentication?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to this from the client, tried several tutorials but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Overview Steps that you will have to do: 1) Create a login form 2) Perform a POST HTTP Request through http client to yourServiceUrl/login